# Android, How to select editor segment of TimePicker?

Tags: android, timepicker

As you know time picker has three segments, two buttons on top and bottom of view and an editor in between.

By tap and holding editor, we can select its contents. The problem that I have is I want to select content of editor just by taping (not tap and hold). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in layout file

```
<TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_timepicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dip"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

Unlike most other controls, EditTexts are focusable while the system is in 'touch mode'.

The first click event focuses the control, while the second click event actually fires the

OnClickListener. If you disable touch-mode focus with the android:focusableInTouchMode View

attribute, the OnClickListener should fire as expected.

Comment: Thanks curious, unfortunately none of callbacks ran after setting focusables :(